# Turning on a mobile phone (SGS2) automatically / remotely

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I want to use my phones as a remote camera system that charges via a solar panel however I was wondering whether there is any way to turn the phone on automatically or remotely.

Thats to say, if the phone runs out of battery and turns off, is there anyway to turn it back on automatically or remotely?

Comment: Are you going to build a custom ROM for it?

Comment: I wasn't planning on doing so.

Comment: Then I think you are out of luck. AFAIK, S2 does not auto-power on when charger is connected.

Comment: Are you, at least, going to root it?

Comment: Its already rooted, did that a while ago.

Answer (score 3):

If the phone is rooted, [here is](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1187631) what you can do.

(Optional) Rename `/system/bin/playlpm`:

```
adb shell remount
adb shell mv /system/bin/playlpm /system/bin/playlpm-original
```

Then create a `playlpm` file locally and put the following:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

And push it to the target:

```
adb push playlpm /system/bin
```

Then give it a proper permission:

```
adb shell chmod 0755 /system/bin/playlpm
adb shell chown root.shell /system/bin/playlpm
```

Now, whenever phone is connected to a power supply, it is going to (re)boot automatically. That's, if its battery has drained it will boot up when a power will be available from solar panel.

Also see:

- [Auto Power on Android when the charger is Connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787634/auto-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected)
- [Programmatically auto-power on the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674849/programmatically-auto-power-on-the-phone)
- [Is there a way to auto-power on the phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274017/is-there-a-way-to-auto-power-on-the-phone)
- [[root] NoMoarPowah!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.nomoarpowah)